# Plugin to another android application

Tags: android

I'm new to android programming.

Does anyone know how to listen for actions that other applications do?

Comment: Please define "actions that other applications do".

Answer (score 2):

You need to be specific. You're probably thinking about BroadcastReceiver (look it up in the SDK). Also, apps talk to each other using intents (there's also a big section about intents in the dev guide itself). You can add menu options to other apps IF they use addIntentOptions. Again, if you want a more specific answer, you need to be more specific in your question.